# Independent Feedback Vertex Set

Tags: np-complete, randomized-algorithms

> In Independent Feedback Vertex Set, we are given an undirected graph $G$, and an integer $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
> The objective is to decide whether there exists a feedback vertex set S of G of size at most $k$ such
> that $G[S]$ (the subgraph of $G$ induced by $S$) is edgeless (i.e $S$ is an independent set in $G$).

Reminder for what Feedback Vertex Set is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set

I read that exist a random FPT algorithm for Independent Feedback Vertex Set that run at
$O^*(2^{O(k)})$ but after a long internet searching, I haven't found it.

Can any one help me to find a reference for it?

Comment: There is a $3^k$ fpt algorithm, isn't there? No need for randomisation. (Misra et al, TCS 2012.)

Comment: @PålGD I think that the best known FPT algorithm is $O(4^k)$ deterministic, however, is very long and not trivial, I need to find a solution that is very easy to represent in front of students in a short time.